# Can't remotely connect to MySQL error (13) with PHP script, connecting through CLI works

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have looked at around 50 of the same question on here, but none of them seem to be fixing my problem. I can't remotely connect to my MySQL database through a php script, **but!!** connecting with  `mysql -u admin -p -h 172.16.2.93` works.

### Here is the code I'm using

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

$dbhost = "172.16.2.93";
$dbuser = "admin";
$dbpass = "mariadb";
$dbname = "registration";

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
```

### The Error

And I'm getting the following error in `/var/log/httpd/access_log` when I access the website the script is connected to:

`[:error] [pid 14797] [client 172.16.2.143:55201] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.16.2.93' (13) in /var/www/html/server.php on line 15`

### Things I've tried

- Changing `bind-address` to `bind-address=0.0.0.0` and `#bind-address`
- Turning off all firewalls
- Running the command `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1`
- Disabling selunix in `/etc/selinux/config`

Edit: The problem seems to have been fixed. After creating the user `remote@%` with `mysql_native_password` I was able to access the database through the script.

Comment: Are you running the php-script and the manual connect from the same machine? No ip specified on the user in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the Mysql is responding from client on port 3306 and you have to mention the port in your mysqli_connect if it a different port ($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket).

You must be missing the port param

Comment: `mysql -u admin -p -h 172.16.2.93 -P 3306` seems to work, but after adding `$port` I still got the same error.

Comment: `code`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1 `code`      I think without =1 just 1

Comment: `getsebool -a | grep httpd` shows `httpd_can_network_connect --> on`, but didn't fix it.

Comment: please replace mysql_error() with "Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error() in die and paste the error again

Comment: `or die("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());` gives syntax error at `,`, I'm not known with PHP, how do I fix this?

Comment: sorry it is die("Errormessage: " mysqli_connect_error()); previous was for printf

Comment: `Errormessage: Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.16.2.93' (13)` output seems to the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

This command will fix the permissions problem for the current session.